# how to get back to the parent process....?

Tags: c

how can i get back to the parent process from a child process(invoked using exec) which is running another program (in while loop).

sample code here

```
do
{
     if(fork() == 0)
     { 
        exec("running a program in while loop..") 
     }
     else
     {
        wait();
        printf("do you want to cont..\n"); // bk pt. 
        scanf(" %c",ch); //yes/no           
     }
}while(ch == 'y');
```

Now, if i run the above pgm..its doing exec and running the other pgm..but i want to switch to the parent process and continue from the statement after the wait();.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; the parent and child are two separate processes running in parallel.

Comment: Really a meaningless question. And also a mismatched bracket.

Comment: i think i didnt put my question correctly..i agree both processes are running parallely..since the parent is in waiting, child process will continue its execution..but the child is in continuos while loop..now lets assume i want to kill the the child process, I can use signals explicitly..but i dont want to do it like that..

Comment: I wanted to continue my parent program by taking input from keyboard., and i'll do fork()..but this time i'll run another program to terminate the child(exec pgm running continuosly) which was invoked before..(a switch case statement can be written before doin fork,so that it will run the exec according to the case's).

Comment: assume: in case 1: i'll run exec pgm continuosly, in case 2: i'll run a pgm which will kill the exec pgm. now..please give me a solution, how this can be done...??

Comment: Is this the same as another question you have posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110738/how-to-terminate-a-child-process-which-is-running-another-program-by-doing-exec - why do you have 2 questions posted for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t, because exec* functions replace the code of your program with the one passed as argument. Just use a fork (and a knife).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "switch", after creating a child you have *two*  threads of execution happening in parallel (at least logically speaking).

If the child exits, the parent should continue with the code after the `wait()`, assuming that really is a valid call to the `wait()` function.

Comment: I think your use of the expression "two threads of execution" may further confuse an already very confused OP. There are 2 separate processes after the fork call - in the context of this fact, his question makes no sense whatsoever.